# How to get Current entity in isolated model azure durable function

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-durable-functions

I have an Azure durable function project created with the in-process model.
Now i want to migrate my project to the isolated model. one of the problems that i'm facing
is the fact that i cannot find a direct way to get current entity in a durable entity class.

This is one example of a method from the in-process one:

```
public Task SomeMethod(string input)
{
    // invoke validate method on the current entity
    Entity.Current.SignalEntity(Entity.Current.EntityId, nameof(Validate));
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

And there are many more similar places in that entity class.
Recently the support for durable entity is added for isolated model but i cannot feature how to port this code.

I am using the recommended nuget for isolated model:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask
```

Comment: `IDurableEntityContext` provides access to the current entity ID and allows you to perform operations on the current entity.

Comment: `IDurableEntityContext` is from the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask` package used with the in-process model. The current code is the shorthand for that. What I need is the equivalent in the isolated model with the package mentioned above.

Comment: @SiavashRostami , did you manage to solve it? i'm having the same issue and cannot find anything in the documentation.

Comment: @smoksnes Not really, i am starting to accept the reality that I have to rewrite my entire durable entity functions decorated with Function and use `DurableTaskClient` to query the current based on Id every time. It looks possible but is so tedious with lots of boilerplate.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and have found that if my durable entity is built using the TaskEntity<T> base class I've got access to the Context property from the base class and the context property has the entity id. However, accessing the Context can only be done after initialization, it's null during class initialization.

Answer (score 0):

According to this official **[MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-dotnet-isolated-overview)**

> Durable entities are supported in the .NET isolated worker
> [image]

But there are some changes in the package and the class as given in the same document.

**While migrating InProc Function to Isolated one,** **this package - `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask` is replaced by `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask`**

And in order to create and access Entity refer this **[MS Document2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-entities?tabs=class-based,isolated-process,python-v2&pivots=csharp)**

Entities can be accessed in two ways: Through calls or signals.

**Calling an entity** involves a two-way communication process. You send a message to the entity and then wait for a response before proceeding. This response might contain a result value or an error, such as a JavaScript error or an exception in .NET. The caller actively observes and handles this result or error after the operation is complete.

**Signaling an entity**, on the other hand, is a one-way communication process. You send a message to the entity but don't wait for any immediate response. Although the message is ensured to be delivered eventually, the sender doesn't wait for, observe, or handle any result or errors that might occur during the operation. It's a "fire and forget" mechanism where the sender doesn't actively monitor the outcome of the signal.

Comment: I am aware of the package changes and have read the document you have shared. I was mainly curious if there is a shorthand way to continue using Entity.Current and not refactor everything to functions, which seems to be inevitable. Thank you anyways.